# How to use for Loop in react native

Tags: react-native, loops

I am new to react native I want to use for loop for showing multiple data. which is come from previous screen from API.

here is my code. I want to show full view in return in for loop multiple times. I am getting data in this => this.props.route.params.data[i].lead_tag_number

```
const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");

  class Browse extends Component { 
    
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state ={
    Email:"",
  }
  this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);  
}

componentDidMount() {
   BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
   
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

handleBackButtonClick() {
  this.props.navigation.navigate("Browse");
  return true;
} 

  render() {
    const { profile, navigation } = this.props;
    const tabs = [""];
       const route = this.props

      return (    

          <View style={{alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center",height:140, width:"90%", marginTop:30}}>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("FormItems")}>
          <Card center middle shadow style={{ height:80, width:"100%" }} >
          <Text medium height={15} size={14}style={{ fontWeight: "bold", paddingRight:190}}>

              
                    {this.props.route.params.data[i].lead_tag_number}
                  
                    </Text>
                    </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
      
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
...
this.props.route.params.data[i].lead_tag_number.map((item, i){
    <TAG key={i} />
});

...
```

Comment: cant find varibale i erro is coming

Comment: Is lead_tag_number an array? `this.props.route.params.data.map((item, i){
    <TAG key={i} number={item.lead_tag_number} />
});`